# npm init для чего нужен entry point: (index.js)

Tags: node.js, npm

При генерации **package.json** для **npm** возникает запрос - 
 `entry point: (index.js)`

**Вопрос:** Для чего он нужен, и что если у меня его нету? Ответьте как можно более конкретнее, *пожалуйста*.

Для чего он нужен --- **он** -- **имеется в виду тот модуль** который будет использовать при подключении в поле **main**. для чего его вообще нужно подключать, какую функцию он несет в себе и как он работает (архитектура) , что как передается как что подключается и.т.д

Comment: Для справки http://stackoverflow.com/q/32800066/2674819

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev - вопрос тут прост, и не требует много времени для того кто знает на него ответ. Просто можно описать архитектуру на пальцах, рисачками, ну или текстом, или как нибудь еще. И всем все станет понятно. Ну конечно при условии, если вы обладаете подобной информацией.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в этом случае можно просто пройти мимо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Модуль в JS, грубо говоря, просто исполняемый файл с кодом.

`main` — поле в `package.json`, нужное самому Node.js для [опознания модуля внутри папки](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). Если его нет, `require` этой папки сделать нельзя. Кроме этого никаких последствий нет, на явный `require` конкретных файлов из этой папки это никак не повлияет.

Рабочий пример простейшего использования модуля-папки:

- ### `./main.js`

  ```
  require('./example')
  ```
- ### `./example/main.js`

  ```
  console.log('hi')
  ```
- ### `./example/package.json`

  ```
  { "main": "main.js" }
  ```

Это не единственный способ. Но остальные не требуют `main` и описаны в документации.

Comment: Некоторые пишут что в поле main можно вписать gulpfile.js, но какой от этого прок, тем более вписывать gulpfile.js(где располагаются зависимости) вместо .js файла с какой то функцией. Зачем?

Comment: @Niko_D с "некоторые пишут" можно написать любую чушь. :) Давайте ссылочку на тех, кто пишет, будем смотреть, зачем они это делают.

Comment: D-side - ну помимо того что я лично видел в инете, где такое пишут, мой бывший  начальник,  в лице главного разработчика, заполнил следующим образом  package.json:

Comment: {
  "name": "package-gui-bem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "author": "none",
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "gulp_watch": "gulp watch",
    "gulp_styles": "gulp styles",
    "gulp_scripts": "gulp js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2"
  }
}

Comment: Хотя в gulpfile.js нету module.exports   вот код gulpfile.js :  http://hello-site.ru/share/fajl/

Comment: @Niko_D спросите у него!

Comment: да не хотелось бы её дергать по такому вопросу, она и так постоянно занята, постоянно у неё куча народа и времени почти нету.

Comment: @Niko_D значит, считаем, что смысла нет, т. к. оснований на то не найдено. Будут -- можно будет думать.

Comment: @Niko_D, неужели вы-таки поняли как связываются модули с помощь поля `main`?)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev - ну так там ничего такого особенного нету)